# How to have different headers/footers for a big table in Ruby/Prawn?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I wanna generate a pdf with ruby and the prawn(0.8.4) gem. the first page of the pdf should have a different header/footer than the following pages. The data will be shown in a table, but the table is shown on multiple pages.

Example:

- first page should have an header height of 60.mm
- the table starts at the first page, below the header
- on the second page there should be a header with a height of 30.mm
- the table continues on the second page, below the smaller header

do you see my problem?

Answer (score 0):

solved.

```
require "rubygems"
require "prawn"
require "prawn/core"
require "prawn/layout"
require "prawn/measurement_extensions"

Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf", :page_size => "A3", :page_layout => :landscape, :margin => 0) do

  padded_box 30.mm do
    move_down(40.mm)
    items = 100.times.map {|i| [i, i]}
    table items, :border_style => :underline_header, :headers => ["Column#1", "Column#2"]    
  end

  page_count.times do |i|
    page_num = i+1
    go_to_page(page_num)
    if page_num == 1
      # header of first page
      text_box "header#1", :at => [30.mm, 290.mm], :size => 18
      image "logo.png", :at => [12.mm,(297-15.78).mm]
    else
      # header 2..n
      text_box "header#2..n", :at => [30.mm, 290.mm], :size => 12
    end  
  end

end
```